# Can we open Robocopy Log while copy is in progress?

Tags: windows, cmd, robocopy

I started using robocopy with /Z switch and log option. I started copying 109+ GB file , it is more  than two days and still getting copied. Since I ran copy with log option (/LOG+) , I cannot see percentage of completion. Is it safe to open log , while copy is in progress to see percentage of completion. Do not want file copy interrupted by opening log file. Is it safe to copy the log file to a different location and open it. Can some one clarify me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not it is possible to open it, depends on the program you're using for that matter: programs like Notepad and [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads/) are able to open a file, while another process is still writing to it, MS-Word is not able to do that. The largest difference between Notepad and Notepad++ for this matter is that Notepad can't refresh the file (or reload from disk, as it is called in Notepad++).

In case you have a Linux subsystem on your PC, you might use the `tail -f` feature, which is written especially for this purpose.

Comment: Hi Dominique, Thanks for response. The content of  log appears to be readable text.  How about taking the copy of the file getting updated to a different location and opening the copy of the file. Robocopy command continuously writes to the log file, In windows will copying the file interrupts updates happening to the file? Or copy will just take snapshot of file at that point of time without interrupting current  writes to file? My intention is I want to be sure no impact to robocopy operation, when I took copy of log file.

Comment: Taking a copy is fine indeed, no harm can be done there. Obviously, this will just yield you the copy of the logfile at the moment you have taken the copy.